# The duration of the access token - is there any way to find it out?

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Is there any way to find out what the duration of the access token is (when it's valid) in case I'm using https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA or the amount of days left (180 days or less) in case I'm using their API from my client in, say, Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can't query for (I just quickly checked the docs again 
but anyone correct me if I am wrong) the token expiry.

When persisting the token make sure to record the created
date. 
Next, establish a daily task to check if any of the tokens are
approaching a 30 day expiry (set a criteria like 40 days until expiry). 
If the token hits that criteria call the API reconnect service.

Here is an example Cron rake task that you can adapt
for Python.

```
task :renew_access_tokens => :environment do
  range = (Time.now-175.days)..(Time.now-140.days)
  accounts = Account.where(qbo_token_created_at: range)
  accounts.each do |account|
    response = Quickbooks::Base.new(account, :access_token).service.reconnect
    account.qbo_token = response.token
    account.qbo_secret = response.secret
    account.qbo_token_created_at = Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: You are right, the developers need to track it for their customer's company/realm.